# how to get pattern score even if less than 0.7?

Tags: java, automation, sikuli

I'm trying to automate a video game using Sikuli API for Java. The game has random effects and usually pattern matching gets score less than `0.7`. Is there a way to get the score even if it less than 0.7?

My code is:

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern image1 = new Pattern("C:\\picture1.png");
Region reg = new Screen();
System.out.println(reg.find(image1).getScore());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can set similarity score through a general parameter:

```
Settings.MinSimilarity = 0.5;
```

It will be applied to general image search if you do it like this:

```
Screen s = new Screen();
s.find("pattern.png");
```

Or, you can apply a specific similarity score to a `Pattern`, like this:

```
Pattern p = new Pattern("pattern.png").similar(0.5)
```

**P.S.**
Rereading your question I see that you ask whether you can get a similarity score of an object. So the answer to that is similar, you will need to reduce your similarity setting first to find the pattern you want. Then if you highlight it using `result.highlight(1)`, all the `Match` info will be printed and you will also see the actual similarity of an object. Then you can adjust your similarity score accordingly to avoid it being unnecessarily low.

**P.P.S** You can have a look [here](http://eugenesautomation.blogspot.com.au/2014/10/understanding-sikuli-match-object.html) to see how to understand the `Match` object data.